# How to iterate all children element and return found element?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a find() function that looking for an element by tag name in the nested structure. I tried go among all children element to find matched element.

```
function find(tag: string) {

    let children = data.children;

    for(let i = 0; i <= children.length; i++) {
       
                if (children[i].type == 0 && children[i].tag == tag) {
            return children[i];
        } else {
            
            if (children[i].children) {
                children = children[i].children;
            }
        }
     
    }
}
```

I have faced with two problems, one is `found` has different scope in loop and not available.

`children` in loop body is also give me syntax error.

Also how to simplify this code?

```
let data = {
  "children": [
     {children: [{tag: 1, children: [{tag: 3}]}]},
   ]
}
```

Also I ahve tried this:

```
function find(tag: string) {

let children = data.children;
let found;

  return function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
         if (children[i].tag == tag) {
             return;
         } 

         if (children[i].children) {
             children = children[i].children;
         }
    }
  }
}


let a = find('tag');
let result = a();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main problems:

- you need to use `<` instead of `<=` or else you'll loop on non existing array items (your syntax error)
- to have your result available, simply return it as a result of the function

You also additional problems:

- to test if it has sub-elements, don't use `children[i]` but `children[i].children`
- when looping on sub-elements you should'nt re-use the var `children`, or else you loose the top level reference `children` and cannot get it back -> the solution for this is to use recursion, this way there is an unlimited level search and no confusion between levels

NOTE: to be testable in the snippet, i discarded the typing of the vars

```js
function find(tag, optionalData) {

    let children = optionalData ? optionalData : data.children;
    let found;

    for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].type == 0 && children[i].tag == tag) {
            return children[i];
        } else if (children[i].children) {
            found = find(tag, children[i].children);
            if(found){
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

let data = {
  "children": [
     {children: [{type: 0, tag: 1, children: [{type: 0, tag: 3}]}]},
   ]
}

console.log(find('1'));
```

BONUS: It's better to use 2 arguments for this type of function, and pass data as an argument, it's more re-usable and you don't need the ternary operator:

```js
function find(children, tag) {
    
    let found;

    for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].type == 0 && children[i].tag == tag) {
            return children[i];
        } else if (children[i].children) {
            found = find(children[i].children, tag);
            if(found){
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

let data = {
  "children": [
     {children: [{type: 0, tag: 1, children: [{type: 0, tag: 3}]}]},
   ]
}

console.log(find(data.children, '1'));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, is it possible to write this code using only loop while?

Comment: Where is recursion stop condition?

Comment: IMO it's better to keep a `for` loop than a `while` here. The recursion stop condition is the `return`: each recursion call returns the result to the previous function, that returns it if there is something found (`return` will stop the execution of the rest of the code of a function)

Comment: Why do you use `if(found)` in if else condition, not outside in loop?

Comment: because this code returns the first result found, when we are looping on children, we want to stop the function execution as soon as we find something, or else it will check next children, and `found` may become false for this children, and then we would have no result

Answer (score 0):

Well you're setting the entire loop into one element whenever it's not found `if (children[i]) { children = children[i]; }`, take that out, also in for loop should do i<children.length, you have <= instead

Comment: What about found, I get typescipt error, that variable never read and I can not reassign children to children[i].xhildren

Comment: @jony did you remove the last part

Comment: Which last part?

Comment: @joey if (children[i]) { children = children[i]; },

Comment: @joey exactly, take it out, that is causing the problem

Comment: Can not get why

Comment: @joey let me know when you take it out though and see the results

Comment: Do you mean to remove this: ` if (children[i].children) {
                    children = children[i].children;
                }`?

Comment: Yes, the same error, found varaible is not available in loop also it does got to deep

Comment: Look at my updating